# Jest test gives me "Cannot find module" when running tests, but the code compiles fine outside of tests. Whats up?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am writing my first test for a large application using NestJS and TypeScript. I want to import an entity which imports an interface from a module in another folder. This is proving challenging.

The project has a structure like

```
apps
..apis
--..web-api
----..src
----..package.json
----..jest.config.js
------..app
--------..profiles
----------.._entities
------------..profile.entity.spec.ts <--- the test
------------..profile.entity.ts


libs
--app-interfaces
----src
------lib
--------profile
----------index.ts <--- the files the test is trying to import and test 
----------gender.enum.ts
----------profile.interface.ts
```

In profile.entity.spec.ts I have:

```js
import { ProfileEntity } from "./profile.entity";
import { GenderEnum, ProfileTypeEnum } from '../../../../../../../libs/app-interfaces/src/lib/profile';
// all that ../../ is what I have to do to get to the import and have it recognized in this .spec file
// it doesn't recognize the @ symbol taking us to the root of the project

describe('Profile class', () => {
    it('should make a profile with no fields', () => {
      const profile = new ProfileEntity();
      expect(profile).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

and in profile.entity.ts:

```js
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { GenderEnum, IProfile, ProfileTypeEnum } from '@ourProject/app-interfaces';


@Entity({ name: 'profile' })
export class ProfileEntity implements IProfile {
    @PrimaryColumn({ nullable: false, unique: true })
    id: string;
```

The profile.entity.ts file works fine when the app is compiled by Docker. However when I run my profile.entity.spec.ts file in Jest, I get:

```
Cannot find module '@ourProject/app-interfaces' from 'src/app/profiles/_entities/profile.entity.ts' // <--- this is a big clue

    Require stack:
      src/app/profiles/_entities/profile.entity.ts
      src/app/profiles/_entities/profile.entity.spec.ts

      1 | import { Column, CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';
    > 2 | import { GenderEnum, IProfile, ProfileTypeEnum } from '@ourProject/app-interfaces';
        | ^
      3 |
      4 |
      5 | @Entity({ name: 'profile' })

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/profiles/_entities/profile.entity.ts:2:1)
```

Is there some special configuration I need to use in jest.config.js to give jest testing access to files outside of the top lvl of the package.json?

here is jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'web-api',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
        },
    },
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.[tj]s$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/web-api',
    roots: ['../../'],
};
```

The line `Cannot find module '@ourProject/app-interfaces' from 'src/app/profiles/_entities/profile.entity.ts'` does not occur when the file runs normally.

Answer (score 8):

Let's say your `tsconfig.json` alias configuration looks like this:

```json
"paths": {
    "@ourProject/*": ["./libs/*"],
}
```

Then you would need to add a `moduleNameMapper` line in `jest.config.js`:

```js
{
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@ourProject/(.*)$': ['<rootDir>/libs/$1'],
    },
}
```

I didn't have an issue with aliased imports being in a different folder, but jest didn't recognize aliases defined in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I replaced @ouProject/ to libs
everything works fine